# Confirmation modal on Bitbucket merge click

Tags: git, bitbucket

Some of our developers forget to go through the pre-merge checklist.

Can we add some type of hook/script or Bitbucket package to show a confirmation modal when they click merge?

An alternative would be using a script to put a task on all open PRs and forcing the devs to check it off. Would that be easier than a modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my job, we have done something very similar to what you're asking. We have added a task to PR's when their build fails. They will have to complete that task, which means fix their code, until they can merge the PR.

This is all being done through a Powershell script that is being run at build time. We are using TeamCity, so we added the powershell script as another build step and setup the appropriate parameters so that the api would work properly.

The Bitbucket API [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html) is very detailed and useful.

I think adding a task is the best option. I am not sure if you are able to produce a modal, but I think the task route would be much simpler.